# Python Facebookchat AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute '_to_send_data'

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying send message to my friend using python.
But I am getting this error.

```
   sent = client.send(friend.uid, msg)
  File "/home/can/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fbchat/_client.py", line 1059, in send
    data.update(message._to_send_data())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_to_send_data'
```

I can login in to my account and ı can enter value of friends also ı can enter my friend name.

Then when ı write my message for example "hello" then press enter, it gives me error.

Codes of program;

```
import fbchat
from getpass import getpass
username = str(input("Username: "))
client = fbchat.Client(username, getpass())
no_of_friends = int(input("Number of friends: "))
for i in range(no_of_friends):
    name = str(input("Name: "))
    friends = client.searchForUsers(name)  # return a list of names
    friend = friends[0]
    msg = str(input("Message: "))
    sent = client.send(friend.uid, msg)
    if sent:
        print("Message sent successfully!")
```

can I see "Message sent successfully!" this message? also modules are successfully installed.

I am working on Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my issue by myself. ı put the answer here maybe someone will have same error and can find the answer here.

My mistake is here;

```
sent = client.send(friend.uid, msg)
```

I changed like this one;

```
sent = client.sendMessage(msg, thread_id=friend.uid)
```

and it's worked!